# How to set part of image blurry android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a view, at header i have a textview, i don't want to assign some background color to this view, but a blur background. I am unable to find out any way to achieve this, Is it not possible in android.

I was able to blur textview text, but not its background by using following code.

```
 float radius = tv.getTextSize()/10;
    BlurMaskFilter filter = new BlurMaskFilter(radius,style);
    tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    tv.getPaint().setMaskFilter(filter);
```

I want to achieve something like this, but don't want to use background color for textview.

[image: -f]

Answer (score 0):

**Renderscript** is a very powerful and optimized "engine" to work with graphics. I have used it couple of weeks ago. you can try. I called `applyBlur()` method to make a simple layout **blurry**, you can just add `TextView` inside the body of the layout and render the layout as blurry. Check the below code snippets:

Method **`applyBlur():`**

```
   private void applyBlur() {
    image.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new 
      ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            image.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            image.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = image.getDrawingCache();
            blur(bmp, text);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

So, in the `blur()` method:

> - At first I create an empty bitmap to copy part of my background into.
> - This bitmap I will blur later and set as a background to my TextView
> - Create Canvas backed up by this bitmap
> - Translate canvas to the position of my TextView within parent layout
> - Draw part of my ImageView to bitmap
> - At this point I have a bitmap equals to my TextView size and containing that part of my ImageView which is behind the TextView

```
private void blur(Bitmap bkg, View view) {
    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    float radius = 20;

    Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (view.getMeasuredWidth()),
            (int) (view.getMeasuredHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);

    canvas.translate(-view.getLeft(), -view.getTop());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bkg, 0, 0, null);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(getActivity());

    Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, overlay);

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
            rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());

    blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);

    blur.setRadius(radius);

    blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);

    overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);

    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(
            getResources(), overlay));

    rs.destroy();
    statusText.setText(System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs + "ms");
}
```

Don't forget to add the "`RenderScript`" into `toString()`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RenderScript";
}
```

**Finally,**

```
private TextView addStatusText(ViewGroup container) {
    TextView result = new TextView(getActivity());
    result.setLayoutParams(new 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    result.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    container.addView(result);
    return result;
}
```

Then inside my `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` method, I just call this like:

```
TextView statusText = addStatusText((ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.controls));
applyBlur();
```